# Displaying horizontal flowcharts in pydot

Tags: python, flowchart, pydot

I am using python module for pydot to make flowcharts. But the flowcharts are being generated in a vertical fashion. I want them to be generated in a horizontal way. Is there any way that this can be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give your graph the `rankdir=LR` attribute, as shown in [this Graphviz forum post](http://graphviz.org/content/horizontal-graph).

I don't know pydot (but I have written a few programs that create graphs in the DOT language), so I don't know the exact syntax you need to use, and I'm having trouble locating docs for pydot, but it appears that you can just pass the attribute as a keyword in the Dot constructor, eg

```
dot_object = pydot.Dot(graph_name="main_graph", rankdir="LR", ...)
```